# Improve a query for the count of records in two different tables in a single row

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have two tables, one contains things that are currently for sale (current_listings), and one contains purchases (sold_items). Records in both tables are associated with a seller (seller_id).

What I want is a single row that gives:

seller_id | count of things currently for sale | count of purchases

I have a query that gives me this (below), but it seems overly complex for what I assume is simple task. I am sure I am missing an obvious way of doing this, can anyone help me see it?

```
SELECT seller_id,
    sum(current_listings) AS current_listings,
    sum(sold_items) AS sold_items
FROM (
    SELECT seller_id,
        count(*) AS current_listings,
        0 AS sold_items
    FROM listings
    WHERE seller_id IN (xxxx)
    GROUP BY seller_id

    UNION

    SELECT seller_id,
        0 AS current_listings,
        count(*) AS sold_items
    FROM sales
    WHERE seller_id IN (xxxx)
    GROUP BY seller_id
    ) x
GROUP BY seller_id
```

Comment: sample data and the expected result would help

Comment: Im guessing that seller_id is not a primary or unique key that's why this convoluted solution.Otherwise a simple JOIN would have sufficed.

Comment: yeah @mihai that's right. Sorry, will post some sample data soon to illustrate this.

Answer (score 0):

```
 select seller_id
,count(select 1 from from listings l where l.seller_id = x.sellser_id) as current_listings
,count(select 1 from from sales s where s.seller_id = x.sellser_id) as sold_items
from sellers x
group by seller_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really able to test this query without any data, but you should be able to do this or something similar:

```
SELECT  cl.seller_id,
        SUM(cl.current_listings) AS current_listings,
        SUM(si.sold_items) AS sold_items
FROM    current_listings cl
    INNER JOIN sold_items si ON si.seller_id = cl.seller_id
GROUP BY cl.seller_id
```

Essentially you're joining the `sold_items` table to the `current_listings` table on `seller_id` and summing (what I assume are) the columns `current_listings` and `sold_items` with `GROUP BY` on the `seller_id`.